# Can multiple doom tokens be removed in one hit in the final battle?

Tags: arkham-horror

If I have two players and my investigator is blessed and has a resultant fight of 11 and rolls 8 successes, do I outright take 4 doom tokens off the ancient one? We spent 2-3 hours slogging through the game and getting hurt at every turn, but when the final battle came, it was quick and short due to this situation, surprising me that it was so easy to defeat the ancient one after all that.

Comment: Did the Ancient One have a combat modifier of +0?

Comment: I suppose Hastur can be +0. Did you roll for your blessing each turn? Was the Ancient One physically or magically resistant? Some of them are definitely easier to fight than others, but being blessed and getting 11 dice sounds like about the best case scenario, meaning that you prepared well. For example if it was Hastur, that means you perhaps had a base fight of 6, kept the terror level from rising (i.e. killed off enough monsters), found a magical weapon granting +5 to combat checks, and had enough luck/sanity to last at least a few turns (assuming the other investigator was helping).

Comment: My situation was similar to what you said, against Ithaqua and having a base of 5 and a +5 weapon (and a one-time +6). Also I had 2 clues and the blessing. Why would keeping the terror level from rising be important? I thought terror rising was simply what moved the awakening forward.

Comment: Also with fight decent, I avoided the 2 damage each turn for 3 turns before it got out of hand with his increasing decrementer to the fight check each turn.

Comment: is it better to remove the question if I accept the duplicate status, or to leave it so others can see this?  I'm happy to remove it at this point.

Comment: Leave it - it provides an additional way for people with similar questions to find their way to an answer.

Comment: As for the specifics, Ithaqua has a combat modifier of -3. With 5 fight and +6 from a weapon, and spending your two clues, that's 5+6-3+2 = 10 rolls. Getting 8 successes, even with a blessing, is pretty lucky, and then in subsequent turns you'd be down to 5+5-3 = 7, pretty different from the 11 you mentioned in the question, expecting only 3-4 successes assuming you keep the blessing. Still, Ithaqua is one of the easier ancient ones, and it sounds like you were well prepared, so it's not too surprising you did well.

Comment: (And Hastur's combat modifier is -X, where X is the terror level. I think Hastur with a terror level of 0 is the only way to end up with a combat modifier of 0 in the base game, which is why I used it as the example.)

Comment: well, I guess mistakenly ignoring that -3 combat modifier is one explanation why it was surprisingly easy. Thanks for pointing that detail of the card out.